# Shipment Extension Attributes

Tags: magento2, rest-api, shipment, extension-attributes

I'm trying to set shipment extension attributes with the following XML;

```
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentInterface">
        <attribute code="order_warehouse" />
    </extension_attributes>
```

When I post the following to it via;

`/rest/V1/order/120493/ship`

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "order_item_id": 718364,
      "qty": 1
    }
  ],
  "notify": false,
  "arguments": {
      "extension_attributes": {
          "order_warehouse": "WAREHOUSE_STOCK"
      }
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error;

```
"message": "Property \"OrderWarehouse\" does not have accessor method \"getOrderWarehouse\" in class \"Magento\\Sales\\Api\\Data\\ShipmentCreationArgumentsExtensionInterface\".",
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: This is even after running set:up, s:d:c, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define extension attribute type  like `string, boolean, int,object etc`  at **extension_attributes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentInterface">
        <attribute code="order_warehouse" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

After that you need to delete files from `generated/code` & `generated/metadata` and after that, you need to do di compile.

### Update

Update `"arguments"` is support object type `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentCreationArgumentsInterface`

see `\Magento\Sales\Api\ShipOrderInterface` and method

```
/**
 * Creates new Shipment for given Order.
 *
 * @param int $orderId
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentItemCreationInterface[] $items
 * @param bool $notify
 * @param bool $appendComment
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentCommentCreationInterface|null $comment
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentTrackCreationInterface[] $tracks
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentPackageCreationInterface[] $packages
 * @param \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentCreationArgumentsInterface|null $arguments
 * @return int Id of created Shipment.
 * @since 100.1.2
 */
public function execute(
    $orderId,
    array $items = [],
    $notify = false,
    $appendComment = false,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentCommentCreationInterface $comment = null,
    array $tracks = [],
    array $packages = [],
    \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentCreationArgumentsInterface $arguments = null
);
```

***So extension extension_attributes will be***

`<extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentCreationArgumentsInterface">`

**instead of**

`<extension_attributes for="Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentInterface"`

Comment: Same error... Am I using the correct Interface in the for="" ?

Comment: I stored extension attribute using `Magento\Sales\Api\Data\ShipmentCreationArgumentsInterface` in `sales_shipment table` but now I need to get that shipment extension data using `shipmentId`. so I tried `Magento\Sales\Api\ShipmentRepositoryInterface` after get method for add that extension data but i faced issue. so please help me. see my detailed question here https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/359113/93504

Answer (score 0):

To resolve that error on my module I needed to define custom type class getters and setters.
Please check the following module which I created to extend the extension attributes for shipment item:

https://github.com/miro91/magento2-shipment-item-extension-attributes